# How to get the value of $scope.imgResult when I using imgly-sdk-html5 with angularjs/ionic?

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I want to build a app using [imgly-sdk-html5](https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-html5) with ionic,but I can't the value of $scope.imgResult in the directive. Please tell me where is wrong!  Thank you very much!

```html
   <div id="imageEdit" imgly >
      </div>
        <div>
            <button id="render-button" class="button button-full button-assertive">保存</button>
        </div>
        <div id="showPic">
        {{imgResult}}
        </div>
```

js code:
.directive('imgly',function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'ACE',
            /*scope:{
                imgCrop:'='
            },*/
            link:function(scope,element,attrs){
                /*
                 * Initialize ImglyKit
                 */
                var kit = new ImglyKit({
                    renderer: "canvas", // Defaults to "webgl", uses "canvas" as fallback
                    assetsUrl: "img/assets", // The URL / path where all assets are
                    container: document.querySelector("#imageEdit"),
                    ui: {
                        enabled: true,
                        showExportButton: true,
                        export: {
                            type: ImglyKit.ImageFormat.JPEG
                        }
                    },
                    renderOnWindowResize: true // Our editor's size is relative to the window size
                });

```
            kit.run();

            /*
             * We have a "Render" button which (on click) will request the rendered
             * image from ImglyKit and add it to the DOM
             */
            var button = document.getElementById("render-button");

            button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // This will render the image with 100 pixels in width while
                // respecting the aspect ratio
                // Possible render types: image, data-url

                var image = kit.render("image", "image/jpeg")
                    .then(function (image) {

                        var $sc = angular.element(document.getElementById('imageEdit')).scope();
                        console.log($sc);
                        $sc.$parent.imgResult = image;
                        $sc.$parent.$apply();

                    });
            });

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You want us to create your entire app? You should read up on each of these parts before trying to create an app with it. There is lots of documentation on ionic, angular and when you know those, it shouldn't be hard to use the imgly-sdk you mentioned combined with the 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it already.
js:

```js
scope.$parent.imgResult = image.src;
scope.$parent.$apply();
```